# Why is my drone oscillating on position hold after I move it a few meters?

Tags: quadcopters, sensor, gps, inav

I have built a 5 inch quadcopter using inav 5, mateksys f722, and M8q-5883 gps. When I enable position hold with gps, the drone is relatively stable, but when I move it a few meters forward, it will oscillate a bit (fly forward, back, forward, back, ...) until becoming stable again. Ultimately it moves to the correct position, but I don't know why the oscillation is happening. The faster I move it to a new position, the greater the oscillation effect (although ultimately becoming stable again). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like there's too much gain in the GPS position holding functions. It's trying too hard to reach a specified position, and overshooting. I've no idea if that's adjustable though.